# How to limit actions in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm using viewsets that has several actions (retrieve, list, create etc...). I also use swagger to get a clean overview of my API. The problem is that it's full of unused method (PATCH, PUT, DELETE) and it messes up the view.

I've tried to do this in my viewsets : `allowed_methods = ('GET','POST',)`

The swagger still has all these unused method. How can I change this behavior ? Is there another way to limit the number of actions in a viewset ? Or maybe the problem is on swagger side ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to compose your viewset view more accurately to get rid of them.

Default ModelViewSet is:

```
class ModelViewSet(
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

Therefore if you just want say the list and create methods, it'll be:

```
class MyViewSet(
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ....
    queryset = ....
```

Comment: Note that if you need to limit requests to just `GET`, there is the `ReadOnlyModelViewSet()` method under the `ViewSet` class.